# How to watch local variables with Emacs built-in debugger on Common LISP?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, sbcl, slime, backtrace

I'm writing Common LISP code with sbcl and slime on my iMac.
I can call Emacs built-in debugger by inserting (break) between code lines or calling with (step) function. Below is a step of debugging procedure.

```
Restarts:
 0: [STEP-CONTINUE] Resume normal execution
 1: [STEP-OUT] Resume stepping after returning from this function
 2: [STEP-NEXT] Step over call
 3: [STEP-INTO] Step into call
 4: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 5: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 --more--

Backtrace:
  0: ((LABELS RECURSE :IN PARTIAL-EVAL) X)
      Locals:
        BINDINGS = ((A . 3) (X . 0) (Y . 2))
        EXP = X
        #:G0 = X
  1: (SB-KERNEL:%MAP-TO-LIST-ARITY-1 #<CLOSURE (LABELS RECURSE :IN PARTIAL-EVAL) {1002A9614B}> (A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
  2: ((LABELS RECURSE :IN PARTIAL-EVAL) (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
      Locals:
        ARGS#1 = (A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 (/ B)) (- Y (* A 1) Z)))
        BINDINGS = ((A . 3) (X . 0) (Y . 2))
        EXP = (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 (/ B)) (- Y (* A 1) Z)))
        #:G0 = (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 (/ B)) (- Y (* A 1) Z)))
        #:G5 = (A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 (/ B)) (- Y (* A 1) Z)))
        OP = -
  3: (SB-KERNEL:%MAP-TO-LIST-ARITY-1 #<CLOSURE (LABELS RECURSE :IN PARTIAL-EVAL) {1002A9614B}> (1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z # #))))
  4: ((LABELS RECURSE :IN PARTIAL-EVAL) (/ 1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z # #))))
      Locals:
        ARGS#1 = (1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
        BINDINGS = ((A . 3) (X . 0) (Y . 2))
        EXP = (/ 1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
        #:G0 = (/ 1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
        #:G5 = (1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z (/ A 3 #) (- Y # Z))))
        OP = /
  5: (PARTIAL-EVAL (/ 1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z # #))) ((A . 3) (X . 0) (Y . 2)))
  6: ((LAMBDA (&REST SB-DI::ARGS) :IN SB-DI::HANDLE-SINGLE-STEP-AROUND-TRAP) (/ 1 (- A X (- C C) (- 9 9) (+ Z # #))) ((A . 3) (X . 0) (Y . 2)))
  7: ((LAMBDA ()))
  8: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (LET ((SB-IMPL::*STEP-OUT* :MAYBE)) (UNWIND-PROTECT (SB-IMPL::WITH-STEPPING-ENABLED #))) #S(SB-KERNEL:LEXENV :FUNS NIL :VARS NIL :BLOCKS NIL :TAGS NIL :TYPE-RESTRICTIONS ..
  9: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (STEP (PARTIAL-EVAL (QUOTE #) (QUOTE #))) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 10: (EVAL (STEP (PARTIAL-EVAL (QUOTE #) (QUOTE #))))
 --more--
```

When I expand each stack, I can track and see some local variables, but not all local variables. How can I add these missing local variables to watch list? When I used other IDE, watching variables was super easy, but with Emacs, I failed to find how to do this.

Comment: It's not Emacs' built-in debugger. It's the SLIME debugger in GNU Emacs. It would be useful if you can come up wih a reproducible example of code and which variables you don't see in the backtrace.

Comment: I do not know if it is true for SBCL as well, but when I debug a CCL program, usually the variables that do not appear in the debugger have not been bound yet, so it is another hint where the error occurred (just before the binding of the first missing variable).

Comment: This code should be private until this Tuesday, I'm sorry to be not able to upload right now, but I will upload next week to show which variable is now shown on debugger in which code.

Comment: @Renzo Because all variables bound will be shown in debugger, so slime debugger don't provide 'watch' function. Do I understand right?

Comment: @imgnpoints, I think so. For the bounded variables in a let, for instance, if only a part of of them is shown, this means that the error is in the initialization of the following variable.

Comment: @Renzo I think you are right, if you add answer here instead of comment, I will vote or select it.Thanks Renzo.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the compiler optimizes things out and thus hides intermediate variables. You could try

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 0) (space 0) (debug 3)))
```

(and recompile your code)

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/debugging.html#the-interactive-debugger

You're also talking about a "watch" debugger function: it isn't available in SBCL but it is in other implementations (like LispWorks). https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/debugging.html#advise-and-watch

Comment: Thank you for advice about optimize function. Currently I should use sbcl, but later I will use LispWorks.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, a possibility is that the variables that do not appear in the debugger have not been bound yet. For instance, inside construct like a `LET`, when several lexical variables are introduced and bounded to some value, if only a few of them are shown in the debugger, this could means that the error happened in the evaluation of the initializing form of the first variable not shown.

Of course this depends also on the run-time system (compiler or interpreter), so it is a good idea to follow the advice of Evhince and set appropriately the optimization options.

Comment: I think your advice is proper, after declaim optimize debug 3 as Ehvince mentioned, all variables are shown on debugger except for those are outside of local scope.